# how to recursively convert from multidimensional form array to the related entity objects

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to convert a multidimensional HTML form array to its related entity (database) object classes with one to many relations and nested one to many relations.
Consider the following input exmaple (human readable):

```
order[id]: 1
order[note]: test note
order[ordertime]: 13. Dez. 2018 09:01
order[position][0][id]: 1
order[position][0][ordernumber]: ADSF-11
order[position][0][price]: 45.99
order[position][0][supplier][id]: 1
order[position][0][supplier][name]: test supplier 1
order[position][1][id]: 2
order[position][1][ordernumber]: ADSF-12
order[position][1][price]: 50.99
order[position][1][supplier][id]: 2
order[position][1][supplier][name]: test supplier 2
order[customer][firstname]: Human
order[customer][surname]: Being
order[customer][billingAddress][id]: 1
order[customer][billingAddress][firstname]: Human 2
order[customer][billingAddress][surname]: Being 2
order[customer][billingAddress][street]: test street 1
order[customer][billingAddress][zip]: 99999
order[customer][billingAddress][city]: test city
order[customer][shippingAddress][id]: 2
order[customer][shippingAddress][firstname]: Human 3
order[customer][shippingAddress][surname]: Being 3
order[customer][shippingAddress][street]: test street 100
order[customer][shippingAddress][zip]: 88888
order[customer][shippingAddress][city]: test city 2
```

We got an abstract class with empty body called `AbstractEntity` which every entity extends and the entities have public member variables for simple types. For arrays its access is private there are `setter` methods as well as `addXX` methods to add one entry at the end of the array (that's why reflection is needed and why we have `$method1` and `$method2`). Additionally it parses date and time from inernationalized `string` to `DateTime`.

I would like to access them as in ORM frameworks style like Doctrine like so:

```
$order->getPosition()[0]->getBillingAddress()->firstname
```

Here is my worker class that does the main stuff:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Ajax;

use MyApp\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use MyApp\Entity\Repository;

class AjaxRequest
{
    private $inputType;
    private $data;
    private $formatter;
    private $objMapping;
    private $repo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->inputType = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'post' ? \INPUT_POST : \INPUT_GET;
        $this->formatter = new \IntlDateFormatter(
            'de_DE',
            \IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
            \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            null,
            \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
            'd. MMM Y HH:mm'
        );
        $this->objMapping = array(
            'order' => "MyApp\\Entity\\Order",
            'position' => "MyApp\\Entity\\Article",
            'supplier' => "MyApp\\Entity\\Supplier",
            'customer' => "MyApp\\Entity\\User",
            'billingAddress' => "MyApp\\Entity\\UserAddress",
            'shippingAddress' => "MyApp\\Entity\\UserAddress"
        );
        $this->repo = new Repository();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $obj = $this->convertRequestToObj('order');
        $this->data['success'] = $this->repo->save($obj);
        $this->data['data'] = $obj;

        $this->jsonResponse();
    }

    private function jsonResponse()
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'success' => $this->data['success'],
                'data' => $this->convertToPublicObjects($this->data['data'])
            )
        );
    }

    private function convertToPublicObjects($object)
    {
        $names = array();
        if (is_object($object) && !$object instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($object);
            $columns = $reflection->getProperties();
            $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                $colName = $column->getName();
                $method1 = 'get' . ucfirst($colName);
                $method2 = 'is' . ucfirst($colName);

                try {
                    if ($column->isPublic()) {
                        $names[$colName] = $column->getValue($object);
                    } else {
                        if ($reflection->hasMethod($method1) && $this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method1)) {
                            $names[$colName] = $object->{$method1}();
                        } else {
                            if ($reflection->hasMethod($method2) && $this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method2)) {
                                $names[$colName] = $object->{$method2}();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (\ReflectionException $ex) {
                    $names[$colName] = null;
                } catch (\TypeError $exc) {
                    $names[$colName] = null;
                }

                if (array_key_exists($colName, $names) && is_object($names[$colName])) {
                    if ($names[$colName] instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
                        $names[$colName] = $this->formatter->format($names[$colName]);
                    } else {
                        $names[$colName] = $this->convertToPublicObjects($names[$colName]);
                    }
                } elseif (array_key_exists($colName, $names) && is_array($names[$colName])) {
                    array_walk_recursive($names[$colName], array($this, 'walkReturnArray'));
                }
            }
        }

        return $names;
    }

    private function walkReturnArray(&$item, $key)
    {
        if (is_object($item)) {
            $item = $this->convertToPublicObjects($item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \ReflectionMethod[] $methods
     * @param string $method
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function checkPublicMethods(array $methods, string $method)
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($methods as $meth) {
            if ($meth->getName() === $method) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $found;
    }

    /**
     * Converts ORM like objects from the request from arrays to objects.
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return AbstractEntity
     */
    private function convertRequestToObj(string $key)
    {
        $ar = filter_input($this->inputType, $key, \FILTER_DEFAULT, \FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
        $baseObj = new $this->objMapping[$key]();
        $this->mapArrayToObj($ar, $baseObj);

        return $baseObj;
    }

    private function mapArrayToObj(array $ar, AbstractEntity $baseObj)
    {
        foreach ($ar as $column => $value) {
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($baseObj);
            $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
            $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($column);
            $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $newObj = new $this->objMapping[$column]();
                $this->addObjectTo($methods, $method1, $method2, $baseObj, $newObj);
                $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($newObj);
                $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
                foreach ($value as $subCol => $subVal) {
                    $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($subCol);
                    if (is_array($subVal)) {
                        if (is_numeric($subCol)) {
                            $this->mapArrayToObj($subVal, $newObj);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->parseSimpleType($newObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->parseSimpleType($baseObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
            }
        }
    }

    private function parseSimpleType(AbstractEntity $obj, $column, $value, array $methods, $method2)
    {
        $timestamp = $this->formatter->parse($value);

        if ($timestamp) {
            try {
                $value = new \DateTime($timestamp);
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                // nothing to do...
            }
        }

        if ($this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method2)) {
            $obj->$method2($value);
        } else {
            $obj->{$column} = $value;
        }
    }

    private function addObjectTo(array $methods, $method1, $method2, AbstractEntity $baseObj, AbstractEntity $newObj)
    {
        if ($this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method1)) {
            $baseObj->$method1($newObj);
        } elseif ($this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method2)) {
            $baseObj->$method2($newObj);
        } else {
            $baseObj->{$column} = $newObj;
        }
    }

    private function getNestedObject(AbstractEntity $obj, array $keys, $levelUp = 0)
    {
        if ($levelUp > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $levelUp; $i++) {
                unset($keys[count($keys) - 1]);
            }
        }

        $innerObj = $obj;
        $lastObj = $obj;

        if (count($keys) > 0) {
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                if (is_numeric($key)) {
                    $innerObj = $innerObj[$key];
                } else {
                    $method = 'get' . ucfirst($key);
                    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($innerObj);
                    $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

                    $lastObj = $innerObj;
                    if ($this->checkPublicMethods($methods, $method)) {
                        $innerObj = $innerObj->$method();
                    } else {
                        $innerObj = $innerObj->{$key};
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($innerObj === null) {
                $innerObj = $lastObj;
            }
        }

        return $innerObj;
    }

    private function setNestedObject(array $parsedObjs, array $keys, AbstractEntity $objToAdd)
    {
        $ref = &$parsedObjs;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $ref = &$ref[$key];
        }

        $ref = $objToAdd;

        return $parsedObjs;
    }
}
```

Let`s say this example calls the pubic method `save`. For some reason, it does the nesting  wrong. Although the other way around, from objects to array using `convertToPublicObjects` works fine.

Here are my other tries:

With bypassed reference depth:

```
/**
 * Converts ORM like objects from the request from arrays to objects.
 *
 * @param string $key
 *
 * @return AbstractEntity
 */
private function convertRequestToObj(string $key)
{
    $ar = filter_input($this->inputType, $key, \FILTER_DEFAULT, \FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $baseObj = new $this->objMapping[$key]();
    $this->mapArrayToObj($ar, $baseObj, $baseObj);

    return $baseObj;
}

private function mapArrayToObj(array $ar, AbstractEntity $baseObj, AbstractEntity $veryBaseObj, $refDepth = '')
{
    foreach ($ar as $column => $value) {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($baseObj);
        $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
        $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($column);
        $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

        if (is_array($value) && !is_numeric($column)) {
            $refDepth .= $column .',';

            $newObj = new $this->objMapping[$column]();
            $this->addObjectTo($methods, $method1, $method2, $baseObj, $newObj);

            $this->mapArrayToObj($value, $newObj, $veryBaseObj, $refDepth);
        } elseif (is_array($value) && is_numeric($column)) {
            $refDepth .= $column .',';
            $refKeys = explode(',', substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ',')));
            $toAddObj = $this->getNestedObject($veryBaseObj, $refKeys);
            $column = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ','));
            $column = substr($column, 0, strrpos($column, ','));
            $newObj = new $this->objMapping[$column]();
            $this->addObjectTo($methods, $method1, $method2, $baseObj, $newObj);

            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($newObj);
            $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

            foreach ($value as $subCol => $subVal) {
                if (is_array($subVal)) {
                    // sanitize strings like userMain,0,1,:
                    $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ','));
                    $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ',') + 1);

                    $refDepth .= $subCol . ',';
                    $this->mapArrayToObj($subVal, $newObj, $veryBaseObj, $refDepth);
                } else {
                    $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($subCol);
                    $this->parseSimpleType($newObj, $subCol, $subVal, $methods, $method2);
                }
            }
            // sanitize strings like position,0,1,:
            $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ','));
            $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ',') + 1);
        } else {
            $refDepth = '';
            $this->parseSimpleType($baseObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
        }
    }
}
```

With if branches inside:

```
/**
 * Converts ORM like objects from the request from arrays to objects.
 *
 * @param string $key
 *
 * @return AbstractEntity
 */
private function convertRequestToObj(string $key)
{
    $ar = filter_input($this->inputType, $key, \FILTER_DEFAULT, \FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $baseObj = new $this->objMapping[$key]();
    $this->mapArrayToObj($ar, $baseObj, $baseObj);

    return $baseObj;
}

private function mapArrayToObj(array $ar, AbstractEntity $baseObj, AbstractEntity $veryBaseObj, $refDepth = '')
{
    foreach ($ar as $column => $value) {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($baseObj);
        $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
        $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($column);
        $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $refDepth .= $column .',';
            $refDepthBackup = $refDepth;
            $refKeys = explode(',', substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ',')));
            if (is_numeric($column)) {
                $column = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ','));
                $column = substr($column, 0, strrpos($column, ','));
                $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
                $toAddObj = $this->getNestedObject($veryBaseObj, $refKeys, 2);
                // sanitize strings like position,0,1,:
                $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ','));
                $refDepth = substr($refDepth, 0, strrpos($refDepth, ',') + 1);
            } else {
                $toAddObj = $baseObj;
            }

            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($toAddObj);
            $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
            $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($column);
            $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

            $newObj = new $this->objMapping[$column]();
            $this->addObjectTo($methods, $method1, $method2, $toAddObj, $newObj);

            $this->mapArrayToObj($value, $newObj, $veryBaseObj, $refDepthBackup);
        } else {
            $refDepth = '';
            $this->parseSimpleType($baseObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
        }
    }
}
```

With an inner `foreach` loop:

```
/**
 * Converts ORM like objects from the request from arrays to objects.
 *
 * @param string $key
 *
 * @return AbstractEntity
 */
private function convertRequestToObj(string $key)
{
    $ar = filter_input($this->inputType, $key, \FILTER_DEFAULT, \FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $baseObj = new $this->objMapping[$key]();
    $this->mapArrayToObj($ar, $baseObj);

    return $baseObj;
}

private function mapArrayToObj(array $ar, AbstractEntity $baseObj)
{
    foreach ($ar as $column => $value) {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($baseObj);
        $method1 = 'add' . ucfirst($column);
        $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($column);
        $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $newObj = new $this->objMapping[$column]();
            $this->addObjectTo($methods, $method1, $method2, $baseObj, $newObj);
            $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($newObj);
            $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
            foreach ($value as $subCol => $subVal) {
                $method2 = 'set' . ucfirst($subCol);
                if (is_array($subVal)) {
                    if (is_numeric($subCol)) {
                        $this->mapArrayToObj($subVal, $newObj);
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->parseSimpleType($newObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->parseSimpleType($baseObj, $column, $value, $methods, $method2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with orm, so not sure if this is what you wanted.

Some hints:

1. I used php 5.6.30 so your milage may vary.
2. OOP is information hiding, that means teach each class what to do, no reflection.
3. Use fields to implement data driven framework
4. Implement magic get and call to dynamically access data and objects
5. Each class must validate its data, not implemented here
6. Each class must throw and catch its own exceptions, not implemented here
7. Use a factory pattern to create the data classes.
8. The interface defines the order class facade pattern.
9. The trait implements the default methods for all order classes.

I toyed with the idea of using XML classes, but this seems to work okay.

This is the class file that implements an order factory pattern. When creating model objects, use the factory class (static, do not instantiate) and don't instantiate the classes directly. The getValue() handles the factory::create when required. The result is the classes create themselves using the factory.

```
<?php /* ormorder.php */
// Object Relational Mapping (OrmOrder)

// order OrmOrder class interface methods
interface IORM
{
//  function initFields(); // this should not be public?
    function toArray();
    function __get($name);
    function __call($name,$value);
}
// order OrmOrder class trait methods
trait FORM 
{
    protected $fields;
    protected $data;

    function __construct($data) 
    { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->initFields();
        $this->setData($data);
    }
    // always override, never call 
    protected function initFields(){ $this->fields = null;}
    // sometimes override, never call
    protected   function setData($data)
    {
        foreach($this->fields as $field)
            if(isset($data[$field]))
                $this->data[$field] =   $this->getValue($field,$data[$field]);
    }
    // seldom override, never call
    protected   function getValue($field,$data) { return $data; }
    function toArray(){ return $this->data; }
    final function __get($name)
    {
        if('data' == $name)
            return $this->data;
        return $this->data[$name];
    }
    function __call($name,$value)
    {
        $attr = $value[0];
        $val = $value[1];
        $result = null;
        if(in_array($name, $this->fields))
            if(isset($this->data[$name]))
                if(is_array($this->data[$name]))
                    foreach($this->data[$name] as $obj)
                        if($obj->$attr == $val)
                        {
                            $result = $obj;
                            break;
                        }
        else $result = $this->data[$name];
        return $result;
    }
}
// pacify php parent::_construct()
abstract
class ORMAbstract
{
    function __construct() {}
}
// Main Order class that does (almost) everything
abstract
class Orm extends ORMAbstract implements IORM
{ use FORM;
}
// you should override getValue()
class Order extends Orm
{
}
class Position extends Orm
{
}
class Supplier extends Orm
{
}
class Customer extends Orm
{
}
class Address extends Orm
{
}

// static class to return OrmOrder objects
// keep factory in sync with classes
// Call directly never implement
class OrderFactory
{
    static
    function create($name, $data)
    {
        switch($name)
        {
            case 'supplier': return new Item($data);
            case 'position': return new LineItem($data);
            case 'address': return new Address($data);
            case 'customer': return new Customer($data);
            case 'order': return new Order($data);
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The model file (and main function). Run this from command prompt

/* assume php is properly setup */

> > ordermodel

This file contains the top level model, the order model used to inspect the data. The toArray() returns a multidimensional array. The OrderModel class must be instantiated and passed the (html) multidimension array.

```
<?php /* ordermodel.php */
require_once('ormorder.php');

// sample database, development only, delete in production
$data['order'][0]['id'] = 0;
$data['order'][0]['note'] = 'test orders';
$data['order'][0]['date'] = '23 Mar 13';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['id'] = 1;
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['account'] = '3000293826';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['name'] = 'John Doe';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][0] = 'Sand Castle';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][1] = '1 beach street';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][2] = 'strand';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][3] = 'Lagoon';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][4] = 'Fairy Island';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['billing'][5] = '55511';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][0] = 'Nine Acres';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][1] = '3 corn field';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][2] = 'Butterworth';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][3] = 'Foam Vale';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][4] = 'Buttress Lake';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['delivery'][5] = '224433';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][0]['supplier'] = '4000392292';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][0]['stock'] = '2000225571';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][0]['quantity'] = 5;
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][0]['unitprice'] = 35.3;
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][1]['supplier'] = '4000183563';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][1]['stock'] = '2000442279';
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][1]['quantity'] = 12;
$data['order'][0]['customer'][0]['items'][1]['unitprice'] = 7.4;

// Top level Order management class
// could also be an OrmOrder class
class OrderModel
{
    private $orders;

    function __construct($data)
    {
        foreach($data['order'] as $order)
            $this->orders[] = OrderFactory::create('order',$order);
    }
    function __call($name,$value)
    {
        $o = null;
        $attribute = $value[0];
        $val = $value[1];
        foreach($this->orders as $order)
        {
            if($order->$attribute == $val)
            {
                $o = $order;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $o;
    }
    function toArray()
    {
        $data = null;
        foreach($this->orders as $order)
            $data['order'][] = $order->toArray();
        return $data;
    }
}
/* development only, delete in production */
function main($data)
{
    $model = new OrderModel($data);
    echo $model->order('id',12)->note;
    var_dump($model->order('date',
    '23 Mar 13')->customer('account','3000293826')->delivery->data);
//  var_dump($model->toArray());
}
main($data);
?>
```

The output should be similar to:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'note' of non-object in C:\Users\Peter\Docum
ents\php\ordermodel.php on line 70

Notice: Trying to get property 'note' of non-object in C:\Users\Peter\Documents\
php\ordermodel.php on line 70
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Nine Acres"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "3 corn field"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Butterworth"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Foam Vale"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "Buttress Lake"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "224433"
}
```

Hopefully this does the kind of inspection you're looking for, probably not the same as Doctrine, but perhaps close enough to be useful.

- UPDATE *

To implement the answer in your code try this:

```
<?PHP
    require_once('ordermodel.php');
   /*..... */
    private function jsonResponse()
    {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(
            array(
                'success' => $this->data['success'],
                'data' => new OrderModel($this->data['data'])
            )
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: I just need a general method to map the multidimensional array to its nested objects. Please don't focus that hard on the example, it's just an exmaple for input data, it can be completely different. Also, the key to class mapping can be different. The member variables needs to be public, because ``PDO``'s fetch mode ``PDO::FETCH_CLASS`` only allows this. To explain my example: ``Order`` should be the outer object. The member variable ``position`` is an array of ``Article`` objects.

Comment: Please point out in the answer what it doesn't do. It takes a multidimesional array and creates an Order (class) tree. Call toArray() and it returns a multidimensional array. That's what you asked for, isn't it? By creating your own classes that override initFields() and getValue() you can create any tree structure you want from any array.

Comment: Well, that sounds nice. But, first of all I need public member variables on each class for simple data types. For array list of objects, we got private member with its related ``set``, ``add`` and ``get`` methods. You also have getter and setter for object member variables. I will upvote this answer, since it is an alternative solution.
How about correcting my algorithm in another answer?

Comment: I'll see what I can do with your code. " public member variables" are dynamically created, so you just use them. e.g. order->id should return a list of customers. This means you can change the database columns/names, update initFields(), and it will still work. I'm looking at PDO::FETCH_CLASS which seems to work with my example, but will get back to you:)

Comment: It seems you can add the trait to your AbstractEntity. If you remove the FETCH_CLASS so the result is pure data, it should work. I don't see where the data is coming from because that is where you need to instantiate the ordermodel class (new OrderModel($data) ). The AjaxRequest->save() would then call model->toArray() to convert the tree to data. You won't need all the other methods in the AjaxRequest class.